# Palm Pre and Visual Studio. Possible?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, palm-pre

The development experience for the Palm Pre sucks, to say the least.  At best you are working on JavaScript in Eclipse with the Aptana plugin.  The intellisense you get is really, really dismal.  You have to be looking at the documentation every 5 seconds.

I was thinking, Visual Studio really excels at JavaScript and intellisense.  Has anyone succeeded at writing Palm Pre code in VS2008 with intellisense, which would require hooking in Palm's Mojo Library?

Is there a known way to hook in 3rd party non-source libraries to JavaScript in Vs2008?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for alternatives to Eclipse, too, but so far it does not appear that anyone has done it.  For myself it felt like too much work, so I just switched to working with several terminal windows open and a browser window to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a long time eclipse user but was disappointed in the eclipse environment for Pre - especially after using the Android SDK which hooks nicely into eclipse (then again the dev environment is Java there).

Have you tried Komodo? I switched over to it and the autocompletion is nice and the webos addon does a decent job. I don't have the professional version so I can't comment on the debugging capability which I'd love to have.

Comment: When you say you switched over to Komodo, do you mean that you switched over to it for Palm development?

Comment: yes, I switched my webos development over to Komodo. Still use Eclipse for Java development.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tell VS08 you want to load the Mojo.js stuff, then it should work. I think you should be able to configure any custom tools you need for building etc. as well.

Personally I'd recommend you check out JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA. They have really good JavaScript support and I've used it with  some Pre-stuff as well.